# How to add Android SDK to IntelJ

Tags: java, android, intellij-idea

I just downloaded IntelJ CE which can create android app but at some step it asks me to add android sdk but when I select a directory where I installed it refuses to accept it so what should I ebnter ?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you actually run `SDK Manager.exe` to download any Android platform files first? After any platform files are downloaded you should specify the root SDK directory (the one which contains `SDK Manager.exe` file) and IDEA will list the available platforms to choose from.